# How can I optimize my SCSS code organization to avoid duplication and improve rendering speed in a Single Page Application?

Tags: css, sass, single-page-application

I have an older SPA that uses SCSS, and I've organized the SCSS files into four categories:

Abstracts (e.g., `variables.scss`, `mixin.scss`, `function.scss`, etc.).
Components (e.g., `login.page.scss`, `dashboard.scss`, `profile.page.scss`, etc.).
Global (e.g., `global.scss` for setting basic CSS).
Index (e.g., `main.scss`).

Initially, I loaded all the files into `main.scss` and included them in the SPA's HTML.
However, this resulted in a large CSS bundle, which negatively impacted rendering speed.

To minimize CSS loading, I started importing the relevant SCSS file for each component directly. For example, I imported `button.scss` in `button.tsx` (React component file).
The drawback of this approach is that I now have to import `abstract.scss` files at the top of every component, not just `main.scss`, for successful SCSS compilation.

I'm unsure if this is an efficient SCSS structure.
Additionally, as this is an SPA, the `chunk.css` files generated by SCSS are loaded when each page loads, and these CSS files persist in the browser even after navigating to a different page. While this doesn't seem like a major issue, it is still a concern.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://web.dev/content-visibility/)

Comment: @Gerard I think your link is regardless of my question. But! That Article was really helpful for me thank you!